# Ссылки в IE

Tags: ссылки, html, internet-explorer, explorer

Доброго времени суток возникла проблема есть ссылка 
вот html

```
<a href="#" class="link"></a>
```

вот css

```
.link{
  display:block;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background:url(img.jpg);}
.link:hover{
  background:url(img2.jpg);}
```

И все бы ничего, но как ссылка в ие не работает, не в одном. Если ссылку наполняю любым текстом то работает. Даже ховер для примера и тот не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/zke85/)**

У вас не закрыта круглая скобка вот тут:

```
background:url(img.jpg}
```

К тому же, нужно указывать **display: block;**

```
.link{
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background:url(img.jpg);
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: это я для примера писал код другой :) сейчас поправлю